# Why can't I import from com.sun.media.sound?

Tags: java, java-11, java-17

I want to use audio synthesizer and midi classes that are included in the Java JDK. MidiSystem.getSynthesizer() returns a Synthesizer. Debugging reveals that the actual class is SoftSynthesizer. So this test passes:

```
    @Test
    void defaultSynth() throws MidiUnavailableException {
        Synthesizer synthesizer = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
        assertEquals("SoftSynthesizer", synthesizer.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
```

But I'm unable to use the class SoftSynthesizer and the interface AudioSynthesizer (which extends Synthesizer, and which SoftSynthesizer implements).

Below, AudioSynthesizer and SoftSynthesizer are commented out, because they do not resolve.

```
   void foo() {
        // Resolved symbol
        Synthesizer s = null;

        // Unresolved symbols
        //AudioSynthesizer as = null;
        //SoftSynthesizer ss = null;
    }
```

One difference is that these libraries and interfaces come from different packages. Importing from `com.sun.media.sound` doesn't work.

```
import javax.sound.midi.Synthesizer;
//import com.sun.media.sound.AudioSynthesizer;
//import com.sun.media.sound.SoftSynthesizer;
```

But both packages seem to be included in the JDK, so why does it matter (if it does)?

Tested with Java-11 and Java-17 (Azul), on IntelliJ, MacOS. Using Maven.

Comment: I didnt think JDK includes any `com.sun` packages past Java 8... On `synthesizer.getClass()`, what is the full package name?

Comment: @OneCricketeer: The full class name is "com.sun.media.sound.SoftSynthesizer". So yes, it's included in the JDK, it's just not reachable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

most of the internal APIs (since) JDK 9 are inaccessible to code outside the JDK
Please see [JEP 260](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/260): Encapsulate Most Internal APIs for details and potential workarounds.

Comment: This seems to be the reason. But JEP 260 doesn't state any details on the rule. And I wonder if I should try to find a replacement for AudioSynthesizer and SoftSynthesizer, in some dependency available on Maven, and what is the best way to find that.

Comment: Why should JEP 260 “state any details on the rule”? The official API consists of what has been documented in [the official API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/package-summary.html) What’s not included there, has never been part of the API. As simple as that.