# com.sun.media is missing

Tags: eclipse, lwjgl, openal

Using OpenAL with Eclipse LWJGL `Com.sun.media.sound.WaveFileReader` could not be imported, so `com.sun.media` did not exist. How should I solve it?

Comment: Recent versions of Java do not allow `com.sun.media.sound` classes to be accessed directly (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70643111/2670892)) What, exactly, is trying to do the import?

Comment: I'm trying to access the WaveFileReader to put sound into my game :)

Comment: Anything that is telling you to access WaveFileReader directly is hopelessly out of date. Using it directly was **never** part of the official sound API. You should use the official [tag:javasound] APIs such as `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream` or `AudioSystem.getClip`

Comment: thanks i used AudioSystem class and it works fine! :)